# Minimizing function of a random variable; MLE over random parameters

Tags: optimization, random-variables, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I have a tricky homework question. I'm not looking for the answer, but rather some help understanding how to think about the question.

I have a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ where $w_i$~$ N(0, \tau^2)$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ given for $i = 1, 2,..n$ , and a formula for generating output $y_i$ as follows:

$y_i = \sum_j w_jx_{ij} + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ ~$N(0, \sigma^2)$.

I am supposed to show that maximizing

$P(w_1, w_2, ... w_d|(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n))$ is equivalent to minimizing the quantity $||Xw - y||^2 + \lambda ||w||^2$ over $w$.

I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to proceed with this. My questions are as follows:

1) How do I minimize a function of a random variable? What does that even mean?

2) How would I maximize the probability? It's clearly a maximum likelihood type computation; I'm not even sure how to compute the probability density function for $(w_1, ..., w_d)$ or how to go about maximizing it.

What I do know

1) I see that the ridge regression must have a minimum in $w$ because its quadratic in that variable. Or at least, I assume that still holds when the variable in question is random

2) I see that (strange indexing aside), we have something like $w = X^{-1}(y - \epsilon)$, where $y, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $X$ is a $n \times d$ matrix. Of course, I have no reason to believe that $X$ is invertible; so presumably the least squares solution (which is more likely to be what I get than an exact solution) somehow corresponds to the maximum likelihood $w$. Again, though, this I'm not sure what to do with the random variable ($\epsilon$) on the right hand side.

I'd appreciate any clarification or ideas about how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: How are you maximising $P(w |(y,x))?$ You're picking a choice of $\{w_i\}$ that maximises $P$ - there's no randomness involved at all. You can do something similar for the latter opt. problem. Also, note that typically, for such continuous problems, $P$ is a probability density and not a probability as you mention in Q 2).

Comment: There is randomness because $y$ doesn’t fully determine $w$. There also another random variable, $\epsilon$

Comment: Yes, there's randomness in the system, but there's no randomness in the procedure you're running after you've observed the data, right? You've already figured out what the distribution is. At this point the optimisation you're running to compute the MLE is a purely deterministic operation, and the question is just asking if two different optimisation problems give you equivalent answers. If you were to then ask what the probability of the output of the MLE to be close to the true, hidden $w$ is, you'll have to start considering the randomness.

Comment: A couple things: 1) The instructions say to maximize the probability. I didn't say that. 2) Not all the data has been observed. I'm not given values for $\epsilon$. I'm only given it's density function. $W$ is still a function of a random variable even with $y$ given.

Comment: I also, again don't know how to maximize the likelihood of getting a particular $w$ because I still don't understand how to find the probability density function for any particular $w_i$ (except that I know it's normal with a particular variance, but that doesn't include my knowledge of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Got too long for comments, added an extended comment of an answer. Do ask both me and your instructor questions - this is foundational stuff that is important to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extended comment elaborating on the theme I was pursuing in the comments above.

---

I think you're overcomplicating this. Suppose I tell you that I have the distribution $P(w;\phi) = C \exp ( - \|w - \phi \|^2).$ What value of $w,$ stated in terms of $\phi,$ will maximise $P$? This is a standard calculus problem. Similarly, suppose I gave you the function $\|w - \phi \|^2.$ What value of $w$ would minimise this, in terms of $\phi$? This is a standard convex opt. Q.

To see how this is relevant here - Note that (in vector form) $y = Xw + \epsilon,$ and so $$P(w|y;X) = \frac{P(w,y;X)}{P(y;X)} = \frac{P(w) \cdot \phi(y - Xw, \sigma^2 I)}{P(y;X)} = \frac{\phi(w, \tau^2 I) \cdot \phi(y - Xw, \sigma^2 I)}{P(y},$$ where $\phi(a, S) $ is the Gaussian density, and so you can set up the optimisation problem that maximises the likelihood of $w$ assuming everything else is constant (it only depends on $X,y$ which is stuff you know/observe).

You should find it this being equivalent to the optimisation 
$ \min_w \mathcal{L}(w; y, X, \lambda) := \| y - Xw\|^2 + \lambda \|w\|^2$ for some choice of $\lambda.$

That's really the extent of the problem here. You're not maximising a function of a random variable, you're investigating the most likely value of that random variable given your data.

Comment: Yep, got it!. Thanks. My understanding of Bayesian stuff was sufficiently mushy that I confused myself.